# Request Length ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in MVC 4 Application on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5, maxrequestlength

I am having an issue with my application using MVC 4 and IIS 7.5 getting a net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errror. The page request size is 4.9MB. All of the content loads but the request says that is has not finished yet, and none of my javascript is applied. I have other pages in the application that all load fine and the Javascript is applied with no issues. There seems to be something going on with this particular page.

Checking around I discovered I needed to set the MaxRequestLength and the MaxAllowedContentLength in the web.config. I set both to 8Mb, with MaxRequestLength being in KiloBytes and MaxAllowedContentLength being in Bytes. This still resulted in the same thing, I double checked in IIS to make sure that the MaxRequestLength and MaxAllowedContentLength were both being set correctly, which they were.

Next I adjusted my query to bring back a smaller amount of data and the page request size was well under 900KB and everything seemed to work fine. I kept modifying my query to bring back more results to see what was the max request size I could go to with the page loading fine. To my surprise once the page request length reached 918KB and greater the request would keep going for about 2 minutes before resulting in a net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errror. Keep in mind this error only shows in firebug as the page seems to display all data fine except none of the Javascript was applied.

I only discovered this issue when putting my application on the production server. Everything worked fine on localhost. I beleive this to be something going on with the server and IIS 7.5 as putting ELMAH in the application I was unable to capture any errors.

At this point I have run out of ideas and things to try. Any additional help would be great.

Comment: Any luck figuring this one out? I've having the same issue when publishing to Winhost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
That error usually is 'cause there is a problem with the Database connection.

try this

1. FireWall permissions
2. If your string connection has Trusted Connection, and your user doesn't have password it can be a problem, you must set  a password or change string connection for sa.

i really hope that it works